# Intermittent background image loading

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I have a background image that loads fine, unless you refresh the page from below the threshold of the image, in which case it doesn't attempt to load.

css:

```
.site-header-single {
    left: 0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 1;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: url('img/main.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 130px 0 141px;
}
```

html:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header-single" role="banner">
    <div class="site-branding">
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
        <p class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
    </div><!-- .site-branding -->
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

I've tried solving the issue by pre-loading the image with css like so:

```
.site-header-single:after {
    content: url('img/main.jpg');
    display:none;
}
```

Which doesn't seem to make a difference, so i tried even adding a jquery timeout function to try and set it after the page had loaded:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.site-header-single').css({'background':'url("img/main.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;'});
}, 1000);
```

I'm not sure exactly what is causing the issue, if there is something in my css that makes it not load it outside the current window?

Comment: Can you include your html?

Comment: What happens if you give the class a position such as absolute or relative?

Comment: My guess is that it is your browser causing the problem. Regardless of where you are on a page, any image should load. You shouldn't have to try to fix it with JS or a CSS hack, because there is no reason for it to be that way to begin with.

Comment: good call @tylerism it does appear to be chrome specific